# Magento SOLR fuzzy search

Tags: magento, search, solr, fuzzy-search, porter-stemmer

I am using SOLR search in magento and trying to use the power of SOLR fuzzy search. But so far seems there is no luck.

I have tried using tilda (~) at the end of search query and also tried to using "PorterStemFilterFactory" which so far is the best stem factory that I know. But it is not giving me any results. For example; I have products named "Shiraz". So a fuzzy search will return same results if search using "shirag" or "shrag".

This is my schema section (I am giving only the english section because that is the only part that I use)

```
<fieldType name="text_en" class="solr.TextField" positionIncrementGap="100">
        <analyzer type="index">
            <tokenizer class="solr.WhitespaceTokenizerFactory"/>
            <charFilter class="solr.MappingCharFilterFactory" mapping="mapping-ISOLatin1Accent.txt"/>
            <filter class="solr.EdgeNGramFilterFactory" minGramSize="3" maxGramSize="10" />
            <!--
                In this example, we will only use synonyms at query time.
                <filter class="solr.SynonymFilterFactory" synonyms="index_synonyms.txt" ignoreCase="true"
                    expand="false"/>
            -->
            <!--
                Case insensitive stop word removal. Add enablePositionIncrements=true in both the index and query
                analyzers to leave a 'gap' for more accurate phrase queries.
            -->
            <filter class="solr.StopFilterFactory" ignoreCase="true" words="stopwords_en.txt"
                    enablePositionIncrements="true"/>
            <filter class="solr.WordDelimiterFilterFactory" generateWordParts="1" generateNumberParts="1"
                    catenateWords="1" catenateNumbers="1" catenateAll="0" splitOnCaseChange="1"/>
            <filter class="solr.LowerCaseFilterFactory"/>
            <filter class="solr.SnowballPorterFilterFactory" language="English" protected="protwords_en.txt"/>
        </analyzer>
        <analyzer type="query">
            <tokenizer class="solr.WhitespaceTokenizerFactory"/>
            <charFilter class="solr.MappingCharFilterFactory" mapping="mapping-ISOLatin1Accent.txt"/>
            <filter class="solr.SynonymFilterFactory" synonyms="synonyms_en.txt" ignoreCase="true" expand="true"/>
            <filter class="solr.StopFilterFactory" ignoreCase="true" words="stopwords_en.txt"
                    enablePositionIncrements="true"/>
            <filter class="solr.WordDelimiterFilterFactory" generateWordParts="1" generateNumberParts="1"
                    catenateWords="0" catenateNumbers="0" catenateAll="0" splitOnCaseChange="0"/>
            <filter class="solr.LowerCaseFilterFactory"/>
            <filter class="solr.SnowballPorterFilterFactory" language="English" protected="protwords_en.txt"/>
            <filter class="solr.PorterStemFilterFactory" />
        </analyzer>
    </fieldType>
```

Also these are the links I have tried:

http://johntwang.com/blog/2011/09/05/Fuzzy-and-Document-Searching-with-WebSolr-and-Heroku/
http://docs.lucidworks.com/display/solr/The+Standard+Query+Parser
http://www.rqna.net/qna/mnuhwh-solr-fuzzy-search-for-similar-words.html

Answer (score 0):

See [Solr Fuzzy Search for similar words](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9883151/solr-fuzzy-search-for-similar-words) and [Solr/Lucene fuzzy search too slow](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10880976/solr-lucene-fuzzy-search-too-slow)

If you are looking for auto-suggest, then using the [EdgeNGramFilter](https://wiki.apache.org/solr/AnalyzersTokenizersTokenFilters#solr.EdgeNGramFilterFactory) is definitely another option to consider.